# epslatex tex-document faulty

Tags: input, gnuplot, epslatex

I want to create a `.tex`document with Gnuplot to insert in my Latexdocument with the following code

```
reset
set terminal epslatex color size 12cm, 9cm font 'Helvetica,16'
set output "test.tex"
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set key off

plot  "Data.txt"
set output
```

When I include the created File `test.tex`either with `\input`or `\include` in my main Latex document it can't compile. It says that basically in every line of code is a **undefined control sequence**. I can't find the reason for that.

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Just as a test, try adding the `standalone` option to `set terminal`, and then compile file `test.tex`.  Does it work?

Comment: it actually does now compile. it has one error concerning the font size. What does `standalone` do?

Comment: It creates a standalone file which can be compiled alone (no need to include inside another document).  Try removing the font specification from the `set terminal` line.

Comment: He still has the same error: `File 'size16.clo' not found! Could not set font size.`

Comment: Do you still get that error with this line: `set terminal epslatex color size 12cm, 9cm`? LaTeX by default supports only from `10` to `12` points font size, `16` is not allowed.

Comment: I now get new errors of the kind `Missing $ inserted`-_-

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error starting from your code above, you should update it

Comment: Error disappeared somehow. Thanks for Your help!

Comment: @giordano Can you make an answer concerning the font size issue?

Comment: @Johannes_B  Done, even though it doesn't strictly answer the original question.

Comment: Forgot about the standalone part, please add this. standalone and font size lead to solving, the mystery stuff would make it off-topic or unclear. *An answer* is better then non, closing and deleting.

Answer (score 1):

In order to better understand what's the problem, it's useful to create a standalone `.tex` file, instead of a file to be included in another document.  This can be achieved by adding the `standalone` option to the `set terminal` line:

```
set terminal epslatex ... standalone
```

Regarding the problem with the font size, LaTeX supports by default font sizes from `10` to `12` points, so `16` is too large.  Replace your `set terminal` line with the following:

```
set terminal epslatex color size 12cm, 9cm font 'Helvetica' standalone
```